# Arithmetic Shift doesnt work on negative num input? Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Tags: c, logical-operators

```
// 1.5 Exercise 6.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int sra(int x, int n);

int main()
{
    int intInputNum;

    int finalValue1;
    int finalValue2;

    printf("Please enter a integer and program will shift the integer 2 places to right,\n it will give value for both arithmetic as well as Logical shift\n");
    scanf("%d",&intInputNum);

    finalValue1 = intInputNum >> 2;

    finalValue2 = sra(intInputNum, 2);

    printf("Logical %d \n Arithmetic %d\n", finalValue1, finalValue2);

    return 0;
}


int sra(int x, int k)
{
    int xsrl = (unsigned)x >> k;
    unsigned mask = k ? ((1 << (8 * sizeof(int)-k)) - 1) : 0;
    return (x < 0) ? mask | xsrl : xsrl;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Please enter a integer and program will shift the integer 2 places to right,
 it will give value for both arithmetic as well as Logical shift
-500

Logical -125
Arithmetic 1073741823
```

Why is this not showing the correct value?

Comment: shifting signed numbers is not a good idea.

Comment: Maybe: But that was not the question above. The question is, why does "sra" not work (which only uses unsigned numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned mask = k ? ((1 << (8 * sizeof(int)-k)) - 1) : 0;
```

I think this cannot be what you wanted.
Example (k==1):
 mask = 0x7FFFFFFF

Then you use "mask | xsrl" which gives "0x7FFFFFFF" (it's an OR operation...)

Just thinking aloud: I think you might want

```
unsigned mask = k ? (0xFFFFFFFF<<(32-k)) : 0;
```

To be really precise:

```
unsigned int mask = 0;
if ( k > 0 && k <= (8*sizeof(int)))
    mask = UINT_MAX<<((8*sizeof(int))-k);
```

and you need to include "limits.h" to get "UINT_MAX".

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't guarantee *anything* (*i.e.* it's either Undefined Behaviour in the `<<` case or Implementation Defined in (your) `>>` case) for shift operations on negative left-hand-side (LHS) arguments.

Comment: Not totally correct. `>>` with negative number on LHS is implementation-defined.

Comment: Stupid question from me: What's LHS ?

Comment: Ahh I see. Good to know (that negative numbers on LHS are allowed); I thought so, but I am no standards expert...

Comment: Urgh. So now I read it precisely: "implementation defined", which is almost as bad as "undefined"; I had hoped it would be defined

Comment: @IngoBlackman undefined behaviour (UB) is *much*, *much* worse than implementation defined (ID). You don't know exactly what IB will do, but it'll do something "useful" and carry on executing your code. With UB you could end up Dante's 3rd ring of hell with your fridge raided, *if* you're lucky!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Paul Evans: In theory you are right. In practice it does not really matter. If I rely on "-4>>1" resulting in "-2" and then some other code uses this computed value this also very well might lead to UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR. So in practice I don't see where the big difference should be.

Comment: @IngoBlackman waiting for you in Dante's 3rd ring of hell - *sucker* :)))

Comment: @IngoBlackman: When you are writing code, using a specific compiler to maybe cross-compile to other platform.